# Redirecting Shop page to Homepage in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there anyway I can duplicate the homepage to be used as content for the woocommerce shop page. So basically just using the same page for two URL homepage and shoppage. Support told me to use redirect canonical URL if I want to avoid creating redirects.

So we can have multiple URLs lead to the same page, to prevent any SEO demerits for duplicate content as long as the link rel=”canonical” is enabled. I tried using the below code in Wordrpress in functions.php but it won't work. The URLs are https://lullyandrose.com.au/shop and I want to use the content of the Homepage which is https://lullyandrose.com.au/

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'custom_redirect_canonical', 10, 2 );
function custom_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if( $requested_url == 'https://lullyandrose.com.au/shop' ) {
        return $redirect_url == '/';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need no to redirect it, just follow the below given steps and you are done...

1. Login as a administrator and go to **Settings** >> **Reading**
2. At the ***Your homepage displays*** section, check out ***A static page (select below)***
3. In the ***Homepage*** dropdrown, select your **SHOP** page and ***save the changes***, you are done

see below given screenshot
[image]

Comment: what I mean is the other way around the content of the Shop page which is in Woocommerce/Settings/Products should also be the content of the Homepage and the content of the Homepage is as is.

Comment: Yeah got it, then you should use short code [products] within the existing home page. more short codes can be find over here https://www.malcare.com/blog/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Answer (score 0):

must be help if you want show home page if request page shop page

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'custom_redirect_canonical', 10, 2 );
function custom_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
  if($redirect_url == is_shop()){
        return $redirect_url == '/';
        
        // and you can use this 
        // wp_redirect(site_url());
        // exit;
    }   
}
```